# Redirect 403 page, .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

**Hi! First of all thanks for helping me out with my question!**

*Summary & Problem:*

I am working on a website and it has an IP whitelist on it

```
allow from **.***.***.**
allow from **.***.**.***
deny from all
```

Now I want that all users without the access will be redirected to `maintenance.html`, but it doesn't work.

*What I tried:*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^maintenance.html$ /index.html [R=301]
```

and:

```
ErrorDocument 403 /maintenance.html
```

Both don't work and will still give the 403.

*End:*

Could you help me out? Or do you know anyone that knows an answer to this question? Please link them to this question or answer it yourself.

Thank you very much! All help is appreciated!

Kind regards,

Justin

Comment: What version of Apache are you using? And you should use a rewrite condition to redirect based on the remote address.

Comment: @PanamaJack Apache version 20120211 (that's all I could get out of 'phpinfo()'). And how to use that rewrite condition?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `allow` and `deny` directives and instead use a conditional statement with `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(1\.2\.3\.4|1\.2\.3\.5)$
RewriteRule . /maintenance.html [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect all users with IPs other than `1.2.3.4` and `1.2.3.5` to `maintenance.html` page.

Comment: My .htaccess is like this right now: `RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^(**\.***\.***\.**|**\.***\.**\.***)$
RewriteRule . /maintenance.html [R=301,L]` , but it doesn't work. The 403 error comes up in other devices but doesn't redirect them to the /maintenance.html page

Comment: You should check from where a 403 status code is thrown while there is no explicit directive for it in .htaccess file.

Comment: The index.html file and the maintanance.html file are just some blank texts in HTML. That shouldn't be the problem I think? I mean, the 403 works but the redirect doesn't.

Comment: I tried putting `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` and before the htaccess and `</IfModule>` after. But it didn't work either @revo